# Azure DevOps Pipeline task Kubernetes@1 use variable for kubernetesServiceEndpoint

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a pipeline in Azure DevOps that accesses my k8s cluster.
I have configured a service connection that holds the required information to connect to the cluster.

When I hardcode the name of this service connection in my pipeline it works great.
However now I've changed the hardcoded value to a variable that comes from a variable group.

Now I'm getting this error:

`There was a resource authorization issue: "The pipeline is not valid. Job Deploy: Step Kubernetes input kubernetesServiceEndpoint references service connection $(aks-cluster-service-connection) which could not be found. The service connection does not exist or has not been authorized for use. For authorization details, refer to https://aka.ms/yamlauthz."`

It's passed to a template as parameter (variable group is referenced in the stage):

```
    #deploy to aks
    - template: templates/deploy-to-k8s.yaml
      parameters:
        kustomizationPath: $(Agent.BuildDirectory)/s/
        kubernetesServiceEndpoint: $(aks-cluster-service-connection)
```

Template:

```
parameters:
- name: kustomizationPath
  type: string
- name: kubernetesServiceEndpoint
  type: string
    
steps:
  - task: Kubernetes@1
    inputs:
      connectionType: 'Kubernetes Service Connection'
      kubernetesServiceEndpoint: ${{ parameters.kubernetesServiceEndpoint }}
      command: 'apply'
      arguments: '-k ${{ parameters.kustomizationPath } 
      secretType: 'dockerRegistry'
      containerRegistryType: 'Azure Container Registry'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it has to do with where the variables are declared. Only global variables (defined in the root of the yaml and not the stage) work for this specific input property. See [this](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/13262) github issue.

Global variables is good enough for me, but other maybe want to user `environments` instead of global variables.

Comment: Hope that resolved your issue. If yes can you please accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hi FerronSW did you include the variable group inside your pipeline. If not $(aks-cluster-service-connection) is unknwon to pipeline.

1 You can include variables group by adding this line on top of your azure-pipeline.yaml file.

```
variables:
- group: {name of var group you have created in library}
```

2. You can also pass this value as pipeline variable from pipeline section.

[image: PipelineVariable]

Comment: Yes I did. I forgot to include it because the whole yaml pipeline is pretty big.